# .querySelectorAll how to take only elements with all attributes

Tags: javascript, class, selectors-api

If i have that string:`

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-name=" + CSS.escape(variable) + "]","[class='nameclass']");
```

It takes all elements with the first attribute and all elements with the second attribute.

How I have to do for take only elements with each attributes?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll` has only one argument. Why are you providing two? Your question isn’t very clear. What is the “first” and “second” attribute that the function takes? What is your expected result?

Comment: If I type that on console, it takes all elements with data-name equal to that variable, and all elements with classname equal to the classname, but I want to take all elements with this data-name and this classname, what i have to do?

Comment: Wouldn't `document.querySelectorAll('.nameclass[data-name=' + CSS.escape(variable) + ']')` do what you need? Or are you deliberately using the attribute-equals notation to exclude elements with additional classes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are looking for this selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".nameclass[data-name=" + CSS.escape(variable) + "]");
```

Please note that I have used `.nameclass` as a class selector which differs from `[class=nameclass]`. The first one selects the elements that one of their classes is `nameclass` and the second one selects elements that have just `nameclass` class attribute.

If the elements that have just `nameclass` class attribute should be selected, the selector should be:

```
"[class=nameclass][data-name=" + CSS.escape(variable) + "]"
```

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved with that:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[data-name=" + CSS.escape(item) + "][class='placeholder matched']");
```

removing the ,

Thanks for all response

Comment: If the intent was to match both `placeholder` and `matched` classes, @Vohuman's solution would still be the way to go, like `.placeholder.matched[data-name=...]`. Otherwise even the whitespace being a little different can cause the selection to fail.